# Laravel Middleware 302 response

Tags: ajax, laravel, middleware

I have a weird behaviour with the Laravel Middleware, surely because of some lack of misunderstanding... ^^

My Middleware does a route redirection if the requirement is KO. And it works well (or not? lol), except when I hit the protected route manually.

IE on the left menu, when I hit the ajax link to /home, if the requirement is not met, then I got a 302 response instead of the redirection as expected.

**My unprotected route**:

```
Route::get('/some-redirection/url', 'Controller@getRedirectIndex')->name('getRedirectIndex');
```

**My protected route**:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['isOK']], function(){
    Route::get('/home', 'NavController@getHome')->name('getHome');
});
```

**My Middleware**:

```
class User2Redirect {

public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $model_logic = Model::where(...)->first();

    if ($model_logic->isEmpty()) {
        return redirect()->route('getRedirectIndex');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

My left menu is a regular load ajax (ie. **$(div_id).load('/home')**)

Why do I get the 302 response when I hit manually the link /home?

Comment: a 302 response code means a redirect. I'm a bit confused as to what's wrong here

Comment: That's why I am here too :/

I tried to figure out why first before posting my problem here.

For me there is no reason to get a redirection code, as I have no solution and no clue why this behaviour, for the moment, to fix it, I avoid using ajax call on the /home and with a direct call to /home the Middleware works as expected

Comment: you are stating *I got a 302 response instead of the redirection as expected* I'm saying a 302 **is** a redirect response. Are you having issues with `.load` not following redirects? Is that what's wrong?

Comment: lol

You are right, 302 is the indication that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header

And the Middleware is also a redirection (logical redirection) so sorry for the abusive language.

I have no error at all, just the 302, when I hit manually the /home url through the ajax call. When I hit the /home without ajax, or directly through the url address bar, everything work as expected.

I find a way to fix my problem but I do not understand it and it's really annoying... :/

Answer (score 0):

register your middleware in kernel under protected $routeMiddleware = [] .

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I already registered the middleware =)

And it works well as said (if I enter directly /home in the adresse bar, the middleware will do the redirection if the requirement is not met)

But if I click on an ajax link to /home then I got the 302 response

Comment: NavController@getHome .. can you show me the of this function ??

Comment: a simple return view =) :return View::make('app.member.home');